# How to working copy after svn update

Tags: svn

I have done svn update which gave rise to conflicts .

Now I want to get my working copy of mine

so please anyone tell me the way to undo the svn update

this is my controller class with conflicts

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChromeExtentionController.class);
<<<<<<< .mine

```
private static final String HttpServletRequest = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/lead/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {

    // return new ModelAndView("redirect:/hello");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("hello");
```

||||||| .r8587

```
@RequestMapping(value="/lead/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(){

    //return new ModelAndView("redirect:/hello");
```

## ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("hello");

```
CustomJMSProducer producer=new CustomJMSProducer();

@RequestMapping(value="/lead/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(){

    //return new ModelAndView("redirect:/hello");
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("hello");
```

> > > > > > > .r9063
> > > > > > >                       mv.addObject("Message", "Success");
> > > > > > >                       System.out.println("My string " + mv.toString());
> > > > > > >                       return "success";

```
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/scraper/submit1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String postDataForChromeExtension1() {
    CustomJMSProducer c = new CustomJMSProducer();
    // c.messageToQueue();
    return "Success";

}
```

<<<<<<< .mine

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scraper/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String postDataForChromeExtension(@RequestBody String scraperInput) {
    if (scraperInput == null || scraperInput.isEmpty()) {
        logger.info("Null in request body");
        System.out.println("Null in request body");
        return "NULL BODY";
    } else {

        CustomJMSProducer c = new CustomJMSProducer();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map incomingRequest = null;
        String url = null;
```

||||||| .r8587

```
@RequestMapping(value="/scraper/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postDataForChromeExtension(@RequestBody String scraperInput){
    if(scraperInput==null || scraperInput.isEmpty()){
        logger.info("Null in request body");
        System.out.println("Null in request body");
        return "NULL BODY";
    }else{

    CustomJMSProducer c=new CustomJMSProducer();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map incomingRequest=null;
    String url=null;
```

## try {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/scraper/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postDataForChromeExtension(@RequestBody String scraperInput){


    try {
```

> > > > > > > .r9063
> > > > > > >               <<<<<<< .mine
> > > > > > >                           try {
> > > > > > >                               try {
> > > > > > >                                   incomingRequest = mapper.readValue(scraperInput, Map.class);
> > > > > > >                                   url = incomingRequest.get("url") != null ? incomingRequest.get("url").toString() : "";
> > > > > > >                               } catch (Exception e) {
> > > > > > >                                   logger.info("Error whle mapping to map" + e.getMessage());
> > > > > > >                                   logger.error("Error whle mapping to map" + e.getMessage());
> > > > > > >                               }

```
            c.messageToQueue(scraperInput, url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while sending HTML to queue" + e.getMessage());
            return "error";
        }

        return "OK";
```

||||||| .r8587
            try {
                incomingRequest = mapper.readValue(scraperInput, Map.class);
                url = incomingRequest.get("url") != null ? incomingRequest.get("url").toString() : "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Error whle mapping to map"+e.getMessage());
                logger.error("Error whle mapping to map"+e.getMessage());
            }

```
        c.messageToQueue(scraperInput,url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while sending HTML to queue"+e.getMessage());
```

## return "error";

```
        producer.send(scraperInput);
        return "OK";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while sending HTML to queue"+e.getMessage());
        return "error";
```

> > > > > > > .r9063
> > > > > > >                       }
> > > > > > >                   }

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getData() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
```

<<<<<<< .mine
            return model;

```
    }
```

||||||| .r8587
        return "OK";

## }

> > > > > > > .r9063

Comment: Can you add more detail around your issue?  You mention conflicts.  What conflicts?  We need more info in order to help.

Comment: I have included my controler class now you can see the conflicts